# How to keep elements in list through out the program in SML?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

Suppose I have to update a list with each call to a function, such that, the previous element of the list are preserved.

Here is my attempt:

```
local 
    val all_list = [];
in
    fun insert (x:int) : string  = int2string (list_len( ((all_list@[x])) ) )
end;
```

**The problem** is that each time I call to insert, I get the output "1", which indicates that the list is initiated to `[]` again.

However I was expecting output of `"1"` for the first call to insert, and `"2"` for the second call,...etc.

I am not able to come with a workaround. How should it be done?

Comment: In functional programming, calling a function repeatedly with the same input will repeatedly give the same results. Why would you expect otherwise?

Comment: You are never updating the variable (and you cannot!). You are just creating a new list whose length you then determine.

Comment: I can recommend reading [Programming in Standard ML](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/isml/book.pdf) by R. Harper. A really nice book!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [side-effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)).
Most of the time functional programmers prefer to use [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), which don't have side effects. Your implementation is a pure function, so it will always return the same value for the same input (and in your case it returns the same value for any input).

You can deal with that by using a *reference*.

A crash course on references in Standard ML:

- use `ref` to create a new reference, `ref` has type `'a -> 'a ref`, so  it packs an arbitrary value into a reference cell, which you can modify later;
- `!` is for unpacking a reference: `(!) : 'a ref -> 'a`, in most imperative languages this operation is implicit, but not in SML or OCaml;
- `(:=) : 'a ref * 'a -> unit` is an infix operator used for modifying references, here is how you increment the contents of an integer reference: `r := !r + 1`.

The above gives us the following code (I prepend `x`s onto the list, instead of appending them):

```
local
    val rxs = ref []
in
    fun insert (x:int) : string =
      (rxs := x :: !rxs;
       Int.toString (length (!rxs)))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Values are immutable in SML. `insert` is defined in a context in which the value of `all_list` is `[]` and nothing about your code changes that value.

```
all_list@[x]
```

doesn't mutate the value `all_list` -- it returns a brand new list, one which your code promptly discards (after taking its length).

Using reference types (one of SML's impure features) it is possible to do what you seem to be trying to do, but the resulting code wouldn't be idiomatic SML. It would break referential transparency (the desirable feature of functional programming languages where a function called with identical inputs yields identical outputs).